# How to determine the route number by coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have a file which contains location's data of the vehicles of city routes which were continuously recorded for a few days. (about 60000 records)

Each line in the file looks like this: 
41.39548,76.91221,1511956810,1511956587,1

(longitude, latitude, unix time of getting coordinates from server, unix time of recording coordinates, number of a city route)

In some lines I don't know the route number and I would like to determine it. I already know how to do it with AI (neural networks and etc). Can I solve this problem by using some statistical methods?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm not sure you supplied all the info necessary to understandd your question, but I'm fairly certain, that what you're asking is way off-topic. If you have a specific programming question, you can ask that, but please avoid asking for opinions (whether explicitly or implicitly) and questions that are too broad. You may want to read [ask] if you want to get some tips on the topic of asking questions that attract helpful answers. On the other hand, there may be a different site in the SE network where your question in its current state may be more suitable.

Comment: Something to try would be to compute a suitable distance from an unknown path to each one of several known paths, and then assume it's whatever has the smallest distance. Computing the distance from a path known only as a list of points to another list might take some care, but I suspect it's a problem with a known solution.